# Liferay SQL data types list

Tags: sql, liferay, liferay-service-builder

Is there any documentation available to get the list of available SQL datatypes used in the *service.xml*?

What value should I use to make the configuration compatible with the following table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_TABLE (
    NAME         varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION  varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
    CREATE_DATE  timestamp
)
```

Comment: Check out the following article: [An introduction to Liferay Service Builder](http://proliferay.com/an-introduction-to-liferay-service-builder/). At the end   (before the "Conclusion" section) it contains a picture with Java to SQL mappings.

Answer (score 2):

It always feels funny to link to the [service-builder DTD](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/definitions/liferay-service-builder_6_2_0.dtd.org.html) (here the HTML version - just see the declaration at the top of your service.xml for the actual file), but you can actually learn a lot from it: It contains way more documentation than actual DTD code, so it's human readable for anybody dealing with service builder. In the DTD you'll find the attributes to declare that you want to connect to an existing table instead of creating one through servicebuilder default mechanisms.

There's another file, which AFAIK sadly does not have a DTD: model-hints.xml. However, luckily there's a [developer guide chapter](https://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/using-model-hints-liferay-portal-6-1-dev-guide-en) on it: This contains quite some extra information, like: max-length of VARCHAR fields etc. . Use this file for more validation or to specify more details for the columns that get autogenerated into your entity tables.